# React + Redux +Rails and webpack without gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, webpack

I am new to React I am trying to integrate react with rails without the gem.  Somehow I succeed to integrate by using web pack. I am facing a small problem while retrieving data to views which was already stored in the database.

Here some brief explanation

```
def index
  @products = Product.all
end
```

With Rails, I can access to that instance variable and loop through that and display data in views

My idea is to assign instance variable to variable and using this React component as below.

```
products = @products

products.map(function(product){
    return(
      product.id
      product.name
    )
});
```

But It didn't work for me.

I hope someone already done it and had good idea about react and rails without using gem help me to find a solution for it

Thanks in advance

Comment: I followed this tutorial: https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-ruby-on-rails/building-a-crud-interface-with-react-and-ruby-on-rails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also newbie to react so, as per my knowledge we can't assign rails object to react directly

I did this to my project for same functionality like you

```
var Body = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return { products: [] }
    },
    componentDidMount() {
        $.getJSON(`/products.json`, (response) => { this.setState({ products: response }) });
    },
})
```

After this you can use 'products' variable like this

```
this.state.products
```

For more reference visit [this](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/ruby-ruby-on-rails/building-a-crud-interface-with-react-and-ruby-on-rails)

Hope its help you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to render JSON on the rails side, then consume it from React. You won't be able to access the @products variable outside of the rails app.

```
def index
  @products = Product.all
  render :json => @products.to_json
end
```

Comment: Yes grizzthedj, I did that but not vorking.

Comment: when you hit `/products.json` in the browser, does it return a valid response? If so, you should add a `console.log(response)` to your componentWillMount function to inspect what is coming back.

Comment: Thanks grizzthedj,I am using an api response.